# How can I lay text over an Overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to create a page that you can press a button, then all previous text hides and a overlay appears with new text on top of it.

I made all of this, but the new text is still shadowed by the overlay.

Is there anyway to position the text over the overlay? (tongue twister)
Right now it is just behind it and kind of dim/hard to read.

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRRVzm)

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1 class="contact-title">Portland Based</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-outline-warning letsTalk hidden-xs-down" id="contact">Let's talk</button>
      <button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-warning letsTalk hidden-sm-up">Let's talk</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="another" style="display:none;">
        <center>
          <h2 class="center2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur sit doloribus officiis praesentium assumenda,
            quod eaque illum voluptatem voluptatum distinctio.</h2>
        </center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 h2.center2 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro";
    text-align: center;
    top: 70px;
    position: relative;
  }

  @keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  @-moz-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  @-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  /* Internet Explorer */
  @-ms-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  @-o-keyframes fadein {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

jQuery:

```
$("#contact").on('click blur keyup', function (e) {
      if ($('#overlay').length == 0) {
        $('body').append('<div id="overlay"> </div>');
        $('h1').hide();
        $('button').hide();
        $("#another").fadeIn("slow");
      }
      if (e.which == 27) {
        $('#overlay').remove();
        $('h1').show();
        $('button').show();
      }
    });

    $('body').click(function (e) {
      if (!$(e.target).is('#contact')) {
        $('#overlay').remove();
        $('h1').show();
        $('button').show();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `z-index` property of `h2.center2` to `10001`

```css
h2.center2 {
  margin: auto;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Myriad Pro";
  text-align: center;
  top: 70px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10001
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great! Will accept answer when time restriction is up.

Comment: Great to hear. A thing to note is z-index doesn't work without the position property set.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `background-color` from `#overlay`.

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter:alpha(opacity=50);
  -moz-opacity:0.5;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 10000;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: This would defeat the purpose of the overlay ;)